# convert delphi record with "polymorphic" to c/c++

Tags: c++, c, delphi

I have some older Delphi code that is used to, as far as I understand write to a binary file a single precision number "looking" as a long integer: (part of the code showing below)

```pascal
type
  GridFileType = file of longint;
  TTrick = Record
      case Boolean of
      False: (MyLongInt: LongInt);
      True: (MySingle: Single);
      end;

implementation

VAR
  li: longint;
  sp: single;
  Trick: TTrick;


PROCEDURE WriteSingle(VAR GridFile: GridFileType; sp: single);
BEGIN
  Trick.MySingle:=sp;
  write(GridFile,Trick.MyLongInt);
END;
```

I only have very limited experience in Delphi (Turbo Pascal), and it's been a long time since I did anything in that - maybe I got it all wrong. 
BUT - how to write something equivalent in C/C++?

I have tried just writing a float to a binary file, but it does not turn out the same...

Comment: You do know about *unions* in C++? You might also want to read and learn about *type punning*.

Comment: Not yet.. looking into that, thanks @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: Do note that using unions for type punning is okay in C, but in C++ it's technically undefined behavior (but it should still work fine). There are other way to solve it (for example using pointers and casting), but that will break *strict aliasing* and may still be UB. [This article might be useful](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/).

Comment: So to answer your question really, one would have to say that it's possible and pretty straight-forward in C, but very hard to do in a safe and defined way in C++, so the best solution is probably to come up with some other solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Delphi variant record translates literally to a C union. In the Delphi variant record `MyLongint` and `MySingle` occupy the same location in the structure. An equivalent C union would look like this:

```
union myunion
{
    int myint;
    float myfloat;
};
```

In the Delphi code as presented, there's not really any need for a variant record. The code could perfectly well be written like this:

```
PROCEDURE WriteSingle(VAR GridFile: GridFileType; sp: single);
BEGIN
  write(GridFile,sp);
END;
```

At which point the procedure seems somewhat redundant.

In your C code you could do just the same, and write the float value directly to the file. There's really no need to alias it as an integer and write an integer. The exact same bytes will land at the file.

Comment: Kludges like that often are caused by lifecycle issues  when the designer started with writing integers but in a later release decided a float would be better. And poor design didn't allow a change of the binary file layout.

Comment: writing a float directly produces the same results as when using the union trick, thanks.